# how to delete an element in a Vector Struct at Rust Anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program, delete, vec

[Vec remove method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove)

```
{
"publicKey": "8bu8S247Z1mcQnkWqNVLrU3L2VwWQ4hg2sEyjK4a9oiG",
"account": {
  "adminKey": "BUa8iJi3PzkKDgDreyc4NG3BruYCTqmiRjPg1g8p2jHz",
  "totalProjects": "3",
  "projectsList": [
    {
      "projectId": "1",
      "name": "asdf",
      "description": "sdfasdf",
      "projectImage": "asdsdfasdf",
      "totalDuration": "1",
      "level": "asdfasdf",
      "totalTasks": "1",
      "tasks": [],
      "totalParticipants": "1",
      "associatedBlockchain": "asdfasdfasdf",
      "cryptoToBeEarned": "dsfasdfasdf",
      "totalTokensToBeEarned": "1",
      "addedOn": "133",
      "modifiedOn": "1",
      "isActive": true,
      "isDeleted": false
    },
    {
      "projectId": "2",
      "name": "asd",
      "description": "sdfasdf",
      "projectImage": "asdsdfasdf",
      "totalDuration": "1",
      "level": "asdfasdf",
      "totalTasks": "1",
      "tasks": [],
      "totalParticipants": "1",
      "associatedBlockchain": "asdfasdfasdf",
      "cryptoToBeEarned": "dsfasdfasdf",
      "totalTokensToBeEarned": "1",
      "addedOn": "133",
      "modifiedOn": "1",
      "isActive": true,
      "isDeleted": false
    },
    {
      "projectId": "3",
      "name": "as",
      "description": "sdfasdf",
      "projectImage": "asdsdfasdf",
      "totalDuration": "1",
      "level": "asdfasdf",
      "totalTasks": "1",
      "tasks": [],
      "totalParticipants": "1",
      "associatedBlockchain": "asdfasdfasdf",
      "cryptoToBeEarned": "dsfasdfasdf",
      "totalTokensToBeEarned": "1",
      "addedOn": "133",
      "modifiedOn": "1",
      "isActive": true,
      "isDeleted": false
    }
  ]
}
}
```

I was iterating over the above list

```
  for i in 0..data_holder.projects_list.len() {
        if data_holder.projects_list[i].project_id == project_id {
            msg!("data entered-{:?}", tasks_data_holder.tasks_list[i]);
            data_holder.projects_list.remove(i);
            //data_holder.projects_list.swap_remove(i);
            
  }
```

I was trying with remove or swap_remove methods
But, sometimes my code can't able to remove the data from the list
[image]

Can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, iterating through a vector while removing elements is very error-prone.  If you have 10 elements in your vector, and you remove the first element, and then you try to remove the 10th element, you'll get an out-of-bounds error! When you removed the first element, you invalidated the size of the vector.

Your best bet is to to use `Vec::retain` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913384/is-it-possible-to-filter-on-a-vector-in-place